# Replicating foreign keys with AWS DMS Full load Ongoing replication - MySQL

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud, database-replication, devops

I am using AWS DMS Full Load Ongoing Replication (CDC) to replicate data from a MySQL RDS to an on-prem MySQL server (both of them running MySQL 8). Before starting the replication process I'm dumping the structure of the master to the replica, because DMS does not replicate the structure correctly. I have an Ansible script to do this, so it's ok.

The problem comes when the guys working on the backend need to do some db migrations (adding tables, editing tables, etc). DMS does not replicate the new tables with the correct structure, it replicates only the primary key, not the foreign key or any indexes.
Did anyone find a solution to this by now? There aren't many projects involving this kind of setup, so there isn't much information available out there either.

Comment: AWS DMS doesn't seem to have the capability to replicate foreign keys or indexes, it's mostly for data. You will probably need to create the schema manually or using a different tool then migrate data. With MySQL you could use mysqldump to export / import the schema and optionally the data, then use DMS after that.